# Add non-stock inventoryitem from code

Tags: acumatica

Im trying to add a inventory item from code but I am currently getting an error when I persist the row.

Source: PX.Data
Target Site: Boolean MoveNext()
Stack Trace:    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at PX.Objects.IN.INUnitSelect`7.INUnit_RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisted(Object item, PXDBOperation operation, PXTranStatus tranStatus, Exception exception)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persisted(Boolean isAborted, Exception exception)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()
   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<Handler>d__4.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__c.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__c.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXActionCollection.PressSave(PXAction caller)
   at PX.Data.PXActionCollection.PressSave()

Here is my code

```
    PX.Objects.IN.NonStockItemMaint graph = new PX.Objects.IN.NonStockItemMaint();

        graph.Clear(PXClearOption.ClearAll);

        graph.Item.Current = item;

        item.InventoryCD = "RP" + product._id;
        item.Descr = product.product_name;

        item.ItemClassID = "REXPRODUCT";

        item.BaseUnit = "PC";
        item.SalesUnit = "PC";
        item.PurchaseUnit = "PC";

        item.ItemStatus = "AC";

        item.TaxCategoryID = "TAXABLE";
        item.ItemType = "N";
        item.PostClassID = "DEFAULT";
        item.PriceClassID = "INPRICE001";
        item.MarkupPct = 0;
        item.MinGrossProfitPct = 0;

        item.BasePrice = (decimal) product.price_inc_tax;
        item.RecPrice = (decimal)product.price_inc_tax;

        item.PreferredVendorID = vend.ID;
        item.PreferredVendorLocationID = vend.DefLocationID;

        if (insert)
        {
            item = graph.Item.Insert(item);
        }
        else
        {
            item = graph.Item.Update(item);
        }

        graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

Comment: Please, add code which describes how you created item

Answer (score 0):

Got it going.  I perform thed the graph.Item.Insert(item) and then set itemclass after that.

```
           private PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem UpdateProduct(ProviderProduct product, PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem item, PX.Objects.AP.VendorR vend, bool insert = true)
    {

        PX.Objects.PO.POVendorInventory vendInv = null;

        PX.Objects.IN.NonStockItemMaint graph = new PX.Objects.IN.NonStockItemMaint();

        graph.Clear(PXClearOption.ClearAll);

        graph.Item.Current = item;

        item.InventoryCD = "RP" + product._id;
        item.Descr = product.product_name;

        item.ItemStatus = "AC";

        item.TaxCategoryID = "INCLUSIVE";
        item.ItemType = "N";
        item.PostClassID = "DEFAULT";
        item.ValMethod = "T";

        item.BasePrice = (decimal)(product.price_inc_tax ?? 0);
        item.RecPrice = (decimal)(product.price_inc_tax ?? 0);

        if (insert)
        {
            item = graph.Item.Insert(item);

            vendInv = new PX.Objects.PO.POVendorInventory();
        }
        else
        {
            item = graph.Item.Update(item);
        }

        item.ItemClassID = "REXPRODUCT";

        graph.Item.Update(item);

        if (vendInv != null)
        {
            graph.VendorItems.Current = vendInv;

            vendInv.IsDefault = true;
            vendInv.VendorID = vend.ID;
            vendInv.VendorLocationID = vend.DefLocationID;
            vendInv.Active = true;

            graph.VendorItems.Insert(vendInv);
        }

        graph.Actions.PressSave();

        return item;
    }
```